# Flask-Nav conditional elements

Tags: python, flask, navigationbar

Is there a simple way to enable/disable elements depending on certain conditions, e.g. if the user is logged in?

```
@nav.navigation()
def navbar():
    return Navbar(
        'Page',
        View('Home', 'home'),
        View('Log in', 'login'),    // this
        View('Log out', 'logout'),  // or this?
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

The define of `Navbar` constructor is `def __init__(self, title, *items)`.

You can construct the items base the status of current user(if  you use flask-security) like this:

```
items = list(View("Home", "home"))

if current_user.is_authenticated: 
    items.append(View("Log in", "login")) 
else: 
    items.append(View("Log out", "logout"))
```

and create Navbar with this `Navbar("Page", *items)`